# How to replace "+" to "Ӯ" and "=" to "ӯ" in my text?

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace, cyrillic

How I can replace "+" to "Ӯ" and "=" to "ӯ" if right or left this symbols have a letters ? I use str_replace() but it replace all that symbols. My text:

```
$str = "+ро ба касе = намебахшид. + метавонист мавз=и =ро гирад. 2+1=3 ва 3 = 2 + 1"
```

I must get result so:


Ӯро ба касе ӯ намебахшид. Ӯ метавонист мавзӯи ӯро гирад. 2+1=3 ва 3 = 2 + 1


When I use `str_replace()` I get result:

```
str_replace(array("+","="), array("Ӯ", "ӯ"), $str);
```

Ӯро ба касе ӯ намебахшид. Ӯ метавонист мавзӯи ӯро гирад. 2Ӯ1ӯ3 ва 3 ӯ 2 Ӯ 1

Comment: Yes, `str_replace` will replace all occurrences. You'll need to work with something like `preg_replace` to do more complicated string replacements.

Comment: I use this `$re11='/=(?=[А-ЯҲҚӮҒӢҶ])|(?<=[А-ЯҲҚӮҒӢҶ])=/';
$re12= '/=(?=[а-яҳқӯғӣҷ])|(?<=[а-яҳқӯғӣҷ])=/';
$result = preg_replace($re11,'Ӯ', $str);
$result = preg_replace($re12,'ӯ', $result);` but it not worked. @ceejayoz

Answer (score 2):

**Edit using unicode properties:**

```
$str = "+ро ба касе = намебахшид. + = метавонист мавз=и =ро = гирад. 2+0=3 ва 3 = 2 + -1=+";
$str = preg_replace(array('/\+(?=\s*+[+=]?\s*\p{L})/','/=(?=\s*+[+=]?\s*\p{L})/'), array('Ӯ','ӯ'), $str);

echo $str,"\n";
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?=         : lookahead, make sure we have after the sign + or =
   \s*+     : 0 or more spaces, the most we can find
   [+=]?    : + or =, optional
   \s*      : 0 or more spaces, not greedy
   \p{L}    : a letter in any language
)           : end lookahead
```

**Output:**

```
Ӯро ба касе ӯ намебахшид. Ӯ ӯ метавонист мавзӯи ӯро ӯ гирад. 2+0=3 ва 3 = 2 + -1=+
```

Comment: Is this the best way to solve this problem? Or you can still optimize the code for large texts? @Toto

Comment: You code also work incorrect when my text: +ро ба касе = намебахшид. + = метавонист мавз=и =ро = гирад. 2+0=3 ва 3 = 2 + -1=+

Comment: Output wrong. It must be "Ӯро ба касе ӯ намебахшид. `Ӯ` ӯ метавонист мавзӯи ӯро ӯ гирад. 2+0=3 ва 3 = 2 + -1=+"

Comment: What happens if the symbols "=" and "+" next to each other are different symbols such as ! ? ; _ ( I will add everything to the regular expression yes?

Comment: @Otabek: Right, but it's very hard to distinguish `+ = метавонист ` and `2 1 + = 3`. The best way is to write a parser.

Comment: @Otabek: see my new attempt

Comment: Good! But Is it impossible to express this rule in a regular expression? If the left or the right of the sigils "+" and "=" there is a letter or space and letters then replace those symbols. Your code replace `"касе = 1 намебахшид"` to `"касе = 1 намебахшид"` but will be `"касе ӯ 1 намебахшид"`

Comment: @Otabek:How then, make difference between `= 1 намебахшид` and `2+0=3 ва`? The regex will become unreadable.

Comment: All the same, you need to write a parser, right? But I never wrote a parser. I have no idea about the parser. Thank you for helping you!

Answer (score 0):

I will use `preg_replace_callback` to do that:

```
$corr = ['+' => 'Ӯ', '=' => 'ӯ'];

$str = preg_replace_callback('~(?:[+=]\s*)+(?=\pL)|\pL\s*\K(?:[+=]\s*)+~u', function ($m) use ($corr) {
    return strtr($m[0], $corr);
}, $str);
```

Comment: Thank your for helping! @Casimir et Hippolyte. But your code replace `"+1"` to `"Ӯ1"` output must be "+1"

Comment: @Otabek: Do you mean you want to replace only when there are letters each side?

Comment: Well digital can also be a space and a comma and signs that will come at the end of the sentence `"Ман ба мактаб бо = 5 меравам! + метавонад маро = +1+2=3 -ро=  +ёд дихад."`

Comment: But still your code is closer to the solution... @Casimir et Hippolyte

Comment: @Otabek: Not sure of that. You should edit your question with more examples and a clearer explanation.

Comment: Well, I'll see all the options appearing and then edit the question. @Casimir et Hippolyte

Comment: In general, you can add this condition to your code: if there is a symbol (glued) next to the symbols "+" or "=" and not a letter, then it does not need to be replaced? For example =1 or +7 or 7+ != not will replace